# On the projection onto the image set of an $m\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I came accross as statement that:  "If $K$ is the image set of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with full column rank, then $$P_Kx=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx."$$

How do I verify this?

I know that the inequality $\langle x-z, y-z\rangle\leq 0, \,\,\,\forall y\in K$ holds if and only if $z=P_Kx$. But I can't see how to show that this inequality is true here.

Comment: There's no inequality there

Answer (score 1):

$P_K$ acting on any element $Ay$ of $K$ yields $A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top Ay=Ay$, so $P_K$ has the correct action on $K$. Any element $z$ of the orthogonal complement of $K$ is orthogonal to the columns of $A$, so $A^\top z=0$. Thus $K$ also has the correct action on the orthogonal complement of $K$, and thus by linearity on the entire space.